# Javascript regex pattern array with loop

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays, function, loops

I have attempted to create a function that will replace multiple regular expression values from an array. This works if the array does not contain quotation marks of any kind, this is problematic when I want to use a comma in my pattern. So I've been trying to find an alternative way of serving the pattern with no luck. Any ideas?

```
function removeCharacters(str){
    //ucpa = unwanted character pattern array
    //var ucpa = [/{/g,/}/g,/--/g,/---/g,/-/g,/^.\s/];
    var ucpa = ["/{/","/}/","/--/","/---/","/-/","/^.\s/","/^,\s/"];
    for (var i = 0; i < ucpa.length; i++){ 
        //does not work
        var pattern = new RegExp(ucpa[i],"g");
        var str = str.replace(pattern, " ");
    }
    return str;
}
```

WORKING:

```
function removeCharacters(str){
    //ucpa = unwanted character pattern array
    var ucpa = [/{/g,/}/g,/--/g,/---/g,/-/g,/^.\s/,/^,\s/];
    for (var i = 0; i < ucpa.length; i++){
        var str = str.replace(ucpa[i], " ");
    }
    return str;
}
```

REFINED:

```
function removeCharacters(str){
    var pattern = /[{}]|-{1,3}|^[.,]\s/g;
    str = str.replace(pattern, " ");
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also wrap all that into a single regex:

```
var str = str.replace(/[{}]|-{1,3}|^[.,]\s/g, " ")
```

although I'm not sure if that's exactly what you want since some of your regexes are nonsensical, for example `,^\s` could never match.

Comment: Typo sorry! meant `^,\s`. Part of the reason I don't like using the array, is because you can easily misplace your commas. Single regex rocks!

Comment: @ThomasReggi: Put spaces between your commas, makes it a lot more legible

Answer (score 5):

The `RegExp` constructor takes raw expressions, not wrapped in `/` characters.
Therefore, all of your regexes contain two `/`s each, which isn't what you want.

Instead, you should make an array of actual regex literals:

```
var ucpa = [ /.../g, /",\/.../g, ... ];
```

Comment: Woah, I was under the impression that `/^,\s/` within the array and not bound by quotes would break the array. Should have tested it first. Thanks.